# Windows 10 Boot loader broke my Linux LUKS disk

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, bootloader, luks

I have 3 disks:

1. Main OS (CentOS)
2. HDD encrypted with LUKS for data (Hardware RAID10, LSI Logical Volume)
3. Windows 10 (Recently installed for testing)

My problem is when I installed Windows 10, it broke my LUKS disk by creating a boot loader on it... Now I can't decrypt my disk and I really need my data.

Can I revert the process with Gparted or other tool ? I hope my data is not destroyed by that boot loader...

I really need help please !

**EDIT 1**
Added some information

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 12000.0 GB, 11999999164416 bytes, 23437498368 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x385dcf68

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

After the answer of Xen2050 here is my result:

```
LANG=C grep -obUaP "\x4C\x55\x4B\x53\xBA\xBE" /dev/sda

164822601573:LUKS��
```

Then hope is returned!

I dd my header with block size of 1 bytes with that

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=luks_header bs=1 skip=164822601573 count=2097152
```

Now I have my luks header, I can confirm it start with LUKS with vi

```
LUKSº¾^@squashfs^@sqsh^@hsqs^@lvm2pv^@LVM2 001^@btrfs^@
```

Now the next step is to rewrite my luks header...

**EDIT 2** 
Added developement

From this unix.stackexchange: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177831/recovering-a-luks-partition

I found the start if my header

```
hexdump -s 164822601573 -C /dev/sda | grep LUKS
2660314f65  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 73  71 75 61 73 68 66 73 00 |LUKS...squashfs.|
```

Set up loop devices

```
losetup -o 0x2660314f65 -r -f /dev/sda
losetup -a
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 luksrecover
```

But I have this message error message:

```
Unsupported LUKS version 115.
```

I think my header is corrupted... Here is the beginning of mine:

```
|LUKS...squashfs.|
|sqsh.hsqs.lvm2pv|
|.LVM2 001.btrfs.|
|_BHRfS_M.f2fs.. |
|...<device.</dev|
|ice>.PRI.TIME.DE|
|VNO.%s-XXXXXX.w.|
| PRI="%d".>%s</d|
|evice>.. %s="%s"|
|.%s.old.1.42.9.2|
|8-Dec-2013......|
|................|
*
|...............d|
|.... n;.0.&.A.v.|
|QkkXa.M<q.P ...D|
|.........a...d..|
|...x............|
|.............T..|
|..........@.....|
|.i@<device DEVNO|
|="0x%04lx" TIME=|
|"%ld"...........|
```

And here is a functional header

```
|LUKS....aes.....|
|................|
|........xts-plai|
|n64.............|
|........sha1....|
|................|
|............... |
|2x.l...r0....8|.|
|...'..[!D..J..tp|
|....?J...~.x"s.=|
|.?.....]981be66e|
|-a0b0-4daa-8a2c-|
|5a6e5d8ed3ae....|
|..q....ZG..}#..,|
|...w..!|..3..>.?|
|.;.&...-........|
|................|
|................|
```

Comment: So Windows has overwritten the LUKS header with its bootloader. Unless you have a backup of the header, there's no way to recover the partition (or its contents).

Comment: You're sure it's really overwritten the LUKS device? Was LUKS on the entire raw drive, there was no partition table or partitions? If your LUKS was on the 2nd or later partition then maybe windows only erased the partition table &/or the start of the first partition. What does the disk look like now in gparted or fdisk or gdisk, and what did it used to look like?

Comment: I assume you didn't backup anything before trying something so risky?

Comment: @FleetCommand I can't Backup the entire disk, I don't have disk of similar size. I think I do nothing very risky until now. Maybe losetup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, a backup of the LUKS header is what you need. But, maybe it's possible that it actually wasn't overwritten and only the disk partition table was messed up and you can't find the start of the LUKS device.

The LUKS header actually begins with the characters `LUKS` then two non-ascii characters 0xba and 0xbe, so you could search your entire disk looking for that string. All in hex, it's

```
4C 55 4B 53 BA BE
```

## Have a Program Search

[PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) should be able to find [LUKS headers/files](https://git.cgsecurity.org/cgit/testdisk/tree/src/file_luks.c) and it's in the Debian & Ubuntu sources, and available for Windows too, tell it to search your entire drive.

Or try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) too (from the same author), it can try searching for lost partitions & may find the LUKS one.

---

## Search "yourself"

Or, you could search the entire drive kind of "yourself" byte-by-byte, with your favourite hex editor (Bless is nice) or with `grep` on linux (found from [this other Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319878/using-grep-to-search-for-hex-strings-in-a-file/17168847#17168847)):

```
LANG=C grep -obUaP "\x4C\x55\x4B\x53\xBA\xBE" /dev/your-hard-drive-device
```

Without the initial `LANG=C` setting it wasn't working for me, my usual "language" is apparently UTF-8, and those options are the short form of *--only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text --perl-regexp* see `man grep` or `info grep`)

It should output the byte where the LUKS header starts, if it finds one. You could then use `dd` to copy the LUKS container somewhere safe, or use that info to create a partition that starts at the right spot, though making a backup copy first would be safest, you don't want to overwrite the header by mistake.

- For example:

  ```
  $ LANG=C grep -obUaP "\x4C\x55\x4B\x53\xBA\xBE" file
  5242880:LUKS��
  ```

  Here, it's 5,242,880 bytes into the file (in linux everything's a file, the whole hard drive too, for example `/dev/sdb`).

Now's a good time to make a header backup, they're 1M or 2M long, so copy the next 2M with `dd`.

`dd` requires a little math to figure out a good block size (`-bs), it tends to read extremely slow with a low block size, the default 512 bytes is probably too slow for more than a few megabytes on a hard drive, 1M (1048576 bytes,`dd` knows M, G, K, etc) should be ok.

- In the above example, it happens to be exactly 5M from the start (5242880 / 1048576 = 5) so this command would copy from 5M to the end of the file/device, writing to the file `outfile` (in the current directory):

  ```
  dd if=file of=outfile bs=1M skip=5
  ```

For a header-only backup, you could use `count=N` to stop copying after N blocks, just figure out how many blocks of your selected `bs=` are in 2 megabytes, above it would be just 2. See `dd`'s help for info.

Comment: Thanks a lot Xen2050! Now I have my header and I know where it start, but what is the safest way to rebuild my LUKS disk ? I don't have another disk of 12tb for backup. I edited my question with all command and result.

Comment: It does look like the LUKS header was at least partially overwritten so nothing may be left of the header (or maybe that's just the first 6 characters of a LUKS header that were written for some other reason). But depending on how many passphrases were stored, and how much was overwritten, something may be left. `cryptsetup` has a repair command, could try it on a copy of 10 or 20MB from the "header" foreward? Or the linked answer on unix.stackexchange shows the header format in a PDF, could try extracting data if any's left? A header backup really is required, unfortunately